# Where to start with making Adwords apps?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I work in search marketing, mostly with Google Adwords, and I want to automate a lot of my daily tasks. Where is the best place to begin? I know html, css, I have a basic understanding of JavaScript and jQuery.

What is the next place to go in order to start making apps that pull data from Adwords? Or even Google Analytics? Does one learn the API? Sorry if this sounds dumb, I just don't know where to go from here.

To be more specific, I want to make a couple things.

My own dashboard (a web page), that shows data for selected Adwords accounts, i.e. month over month conversion rate.

A page that auto-generates reports. This is similar to the dashboard, but is client facing.

As a noob, what should I learn more about next? Thank you so much for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

First, hone your knowledge of Javascript. Second, look into Adwords Scripts and MCC Scripts that you can write.

The scripts will allow you to kind of interface between Adwords and an external app (like Google Docs, for example) without going through the pain of having to learn the intricacies of using the AdWords/Analytics API.

That would be a great start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this all yourself, you certainly would be need to get acquainted with the [Google Analytics Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/).  If you are only concerned about reporting, I don't think you will need to worry about utilizing the AdWords API, provided you have your Adwords and Analytics linked.

The API will let you pull data from your Google Analytics.  You will then need to chart that data.  One solution is to get acquainted with the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/).  Or any another charting library of your choice.

There are also many third party reporting solutions.  These can be found on the [Google Analytics Partner Page](http://www.google.com/analytics/partners/search/apps?category=111&page=2).  A lot of these are tailored specifically for SEM/SEO agencies.

I also encourage you to check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/embeddedanalyticsforagencies.html).  This is a service I have created.  And we cater directly to agencies looking to embed Analytics and Adwords based reports directly into websites for their own customers to view.